# If an iPhone stolen and they restart it can it be tracked?

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone

If my iPhone was stolen and they reset and everything got deleted will I still be able to track it if everything has be deleted?

Comment: The answer in the linked question is three years old, Apple made a lot of changes to Find My iPhone in the meantime. Maybe we can get an answer based on the current situation here.

Answer (score 1):

If they deleted everything, then no... I guess you could then contact the police or something, resetting the iphone will cause the "find my iphone" feature to be disabled so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

Nope they can't track it so its pretty much useless I wouldn't even try just a waste of time I just demanded another phone and the company eventually gave in

Answer (score 0):

No, resetting the iPhone will disable Find my iPhone and your iCloud data will be deleted.